# GRM or mixed effect models

Tags: r, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, nonlinear-regression, mixed-model

In experiment I have measured the grow of one plant on 40 locations. At one location different number of plants were measured, but always the same species. The distribution of response variable is log-normal. I wanted to show the distribution in the post but it is not possible because I'm new user of stats.stackexchange.

I have additional explanatory variables like altitude, soil type, precipitation ect. and would like to prepare the model of variables that explain the grow of this plant.
Because the distribution of response variable is not normal I thought to use the GLM (`glm` function in R with `family=gamma`).
Should I include also the grouping variable "location" and because of this the use of Mixed Effect Models (`nlme` function in R package `lme`) would be more appropriate?

How would the code look like?
Could you recommend me some literature?
I hope that the question is well described.

Comment: I think you are on the right track, and including location as the random effect makes perfect sense.